# sorting of a multy dimensional array php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I need to sort an array like

```
$arrayName = array(0 => array('val' => 100), 1 => array('val' => 75),3 => array('val' => 10), 4 => array('val' => 15));
```

I need output like this

```
$arrayName = array(3 => array('val' => 10), 4 => array('val' => 15),1 => array('val' => 75), 0 => array('val' => 100));
```

Comment: have u tried http://php.net/usort

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Use `asort()` so you don't lose your key's)

```
<?php

    $arrayName = array(0 => array('val' => 100), 1 => array('val' => 75),3 => array('val' => 10), 4 => array('val' => 15));
    asort($arrayName);

    print_r($arrayName);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array ( [3] => Array ( [val] => 10 ) [4] => Array ( [val] => 15 ) [1] => Array ( [val] => 75 ) [0] => Array ( [val] => 100 ) )
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
foreach ($arrayName as $key => $row) {
$data[$key]  = $row[0]; 
// of course, replace 0 with whatever is the date field's index
}
array_multisort($data, SORT_ASC, $arrayName);
```

Comment: with multisort you will lose the key's

Answer (score 2):

Use [`krsort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.krsort.php) for sort array by key in descending order

```
krsort($arrayName);
print_r($arrayName);
```

Answer (score 2):

Rizier123 has the simplest solution.  If you needed to have more complex comparisons (say your array had multiple keys/values that you want to sort on), you could use `uasort` and create a custom comparison function (`uasort` preserves array keys while `usort` does not). For example:

```
public function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['val'] == $b['val']) {
        return 0;
    }

    return ($a['val'] < $b['val']) ? -1 : 1;
}

uasort($arrayName, 'cmp');
```